# Difference in running a Python script in background versus running it as a system service?

Tags: linux, debian, python, services, python3

I have a Debian 10 VPS and I want to run a Python script on it 24/7.

What would be the difference between running it in background and installing it as a system service?

What is the best way to achieve my script running in background 24/7?

Answer (score 0):

## You can “roll your own” Python service logic, but why reinvent the wheel when system service management is standardized and a best practice industry-wide?

If you run any script in the background, it simply runs under your user in the background and you are the only person who can deal with it.

If it runs as a service, the system handles keeping the application up. The benefit is automatic restart on reboot and such. And even using established tools to manage the service. You could possibly do similar work just in Python, but you would be reinventing the wheel and doing was is essentially sysadmin work instead of being a developer.

What it comes down to is your application will technically work either way. But using established best practices for keeping scripts and applications up and running saves you tons of headaches in the long run and is a healthier approach to development and deployment.